# what's the meaning of this icon in TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

After a merge the icons reprensenting folder a has change to this yellow icon representing one parent folder and a child one (With the label Appls beside) :
[image: TFS 2013 Icon representing one parent folder and a child one]

Anyone has an idea what's the meaning of this icon? All the other folder icon are normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grey icon means that the folder has been converted to a Branch Root and that it (optionally) has a branch relationship with another Branch elsewhere in the repository.

Note: *You can convert a folder to a branch using the Convert to Branch option in the Source Control Explorer without directly creating a relationship to another branch.*

[image]

For more information see the [Branch folders and files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx) topic on MSDN.

The yellow "Branched folder" icon is not a standard icon of Visual Studio, but a feature if the [TFS Source Control Explorer Extensions from the Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dc925252-2e11-46df-9cd0-af4b8097ca4f).

[image]

With the File Icon change option off:

[image]

Wit the File Icon change option on:

[image]

From the extension gallery description:

> ### File icon change
>
> In the file list on the left side of Source Control Explorer window
>   are branched files displayed with changed icon.
>
> [image: File List]
>
> Icon [image: Share Target] is displayed at files that are target of Branch
>   operation or if file is branched only to one location. If file is
>   branched to more than one location its icon is changed to icon [image: Share Source].

Comment: Sorry I updated my question because I'm speaking of the second icon, the yellow one with Appls beside

Comment: Hmm Interesting, any chance you have the TFS Source Control Explorer Extensions installed?

Comment: Yeah I've just checked and I do have this extension installed on this dev machine!! Great answer! thank you!!

Comment: Great extension by the way, though I usually turn this feature off.

Comment: What are the top-level folders called? The ones with the two-person "team" icons?

Comment: Those are Team Projects / TFVC repositories.